Read xml and generate dynamic object properties
Complete the XMLReader class, to which we pass XML document as string to constructor, it converts the XML document into a dynamic object, in which the nodes are accessible as the object's properties and the inner XML is accessible by the text property.
Complete the class so that it works recursively for XMLs with any level.
xml_string = "<note> <to>Tove</to>    <from>Jani</from>    <heading>Reminder</heading>    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>  </note>  "

This is my code:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class XmlReader:
    def __init__(self, xml=None):
        self.text = ""
        if xml is not None:
            doc = ET.fromstring(xml)
            self.text = ET.tostring(doc).decode('ascii')
            xml = XmlReader()
            xml.text = doc.text
            setattr(self, doc.tag, xml)
            
xml_string = \
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + \
                    "<note>" + \
                      "<to>Tove</to>" +\
                      "<from>Jani</from>" + \
                      "<heading>Reminder</heading>" + \
                      "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>" +\
                    "</note>"
                    
xmlObj = XmlReader(xml_string)
print(xmlObj.text)
print(xmlObj.note.text)
print(xmlObj.note.to.text)

Expected result is :
"<note> <to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"

"<to>Tove</to>"

"<from>Jani</from>"

With my code, it is throwing error :
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(xmlObj.note.to.text)
AttributeError: 'XmlReader' object has no attribute 'to'

What is the correct way to solve this program?

This sounds like homework. The correct way to solve this is to do what they ask you to, not, well, parsing XML, then stringifying it, then trying to set an attribute on a str.

Also, didn't you ask this earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78461008/parse-xml-using-python-throwing-exception

@AKX, yes, similar one. But this question is about generating dynamic objects, so completely different.

Try this

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class XmlReader:
    def __init__(self, xml=None):
        if xml:
            doc = ET.fromstring(xml)
            self._parse_element(doc)
            setattr(self, doc.tag, self)

    def _parse_element(self, element):
        self.text = ET.tostring(element, encoding='unicode')
        for child in element:
            child_reader = XmlReader()
            child_reader._parse_element(child)
            tag = child.tag
            if tag == "from":
                tag = "from_"
            if not hasattr(self, tag):
                setattr(self, tag, child_reader)
            else:
                existing = getattr(self, tag)
                if isinstance(existing, list):
                    existing.append(child_reader)
                else:
                    setattr(self, tag, [existing, child_reader])
# Example usage
xml_string = \
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + \
                    "<note>" + \
                      "<to>Tove</to>" +\
                      "<from>Jani</from>" + \
                      "<heading>Reminder</heading>" + \
                      "<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>" +\
                    "</note>"

xmlObj = XmlReader(xml_string)
print(xmlObj.text)             # Should print the entire XML content
print(xmlObj.note.text)        
print(xmlObj.note.to.text)     # Should print "Tove"
print(xmlObj.note.from_.text)  # Should print "Jani"


Thanks, can you please add comments also to understand this.

print(xmlObj.note.to.text) is printing <to>Tove</to>, now if I want to print Tove using print(xmlObj.note.to.text), what changes should be made in the code?

Try print(xmlObj.note.to.text.replace("<to>").replace("</to>"))

@ChinmayT, I don't want to change the print(xmlObj.note.to.text) command. It should directly print Tove

@muhammad-ali, can you please add comments, also I want print(xmlObj.note.to.text) to print Tove instead of  <to>Tove</to>
